# Texture repeating

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I want to repeat small 2x2 pixels texture on a bigger quad, for instance, 50x50 pixels.

Set vertices -

```
float X = 100, Y = 100, Width = 50, Height = 50;
float TextureLeft = 0, TextureTop = 0, TextureRight = 25, TextureBottom = 25;

Vertices[0].x = X;
Vertices[0].y = Y + Height;
Vertices[0].z = 0;
Vertices[0].rhw = 1;
Vertices[0].tu = TextureLeft;
Vertices[0].tv = TextureBottom;

Vertices[1].x = X;
Vertices[1].y = Y;
Vertices[1].z = 0;
Vertices[1].rhw = 1;
Vertices[1].tu = TextureLeft;
Vertices[1].tv = TextureTop;

Vertices[2].x = X + Width;
Vertices[2].y = Y;
Vertices[2].z = 0;
Vertices[2].rhw = 1;
Vertices[2].tu = TextureRight;
Vertices[2].tv = TextureTop;

Vertices[3].x = X;
Vertices[3].y = Y + Height;
Vertices[3].z = 0;
Vertices[3].rhw = 1;
Vertices[3].tu = TextureLeft;
Vertices[3].tv = TextureBottom;

Vertices[4].x = X + Width;
Vertices[4].y = Y;
Vertices[4].z = 0;
Vertices[4].rhw = 1;
Vertices[4].tu = TextureRight;
Vertices[4].tv = TextureTop;

Vertices[5].x = X + Width;
Vertices[5].y = Y + Height;
Vertices[5].z = 0;
Vertices[5].rhw = 1;
Vertices[5].tu = TextureRight;
Vertices[5].tv = TextureBottom;
```

Draw -

```
DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 6);
```

Problem is "glitch" in the edge between the triangles, probably because of wrong vertices coordinates and also "glitch" on quad borders.

Original texture - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8l0Z.png

Result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tub9W.png

Comment: You haven't specified the rasterizer state that you are using. Maybe you are missing the texture clamp/repeat settings. What else do you call before the DrawPrimitive to setup texture ?

Comment: Could you tell me which rasterizer / clamp / repeat settings should be set? I draw empty scene with single texture quad.

Comment: The "repeat" setting is called "wrap" in DX. I've added the answer with the link to MSDN, if you have questions about the values.

Comment: Maybe it's a mipmapping problem try to load the texture without mipmap-generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the call to DrawPrimitive you should setup the texture wrapping as in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// For the textures other than the first one use "D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0+index"
YourDevice->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
YourDevice->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
```

To eliminate the glitch at the diagonal you may use the single Quad instead of two triangles.

The problem at the edges is considered [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/359580-dx9d3d-texture-mapping-problems/). You have to add small offset to each texture coordinate. "Small" means a normalized half of the pixel. If your texture resolution is 512x512, then add (0.5/512.0) to each of the u/v coords.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, but this made no changes at all. Still "glitch" at borders and in the edge between triangles.

Comment: I've added a little on this problem, hope it helps. First try adding the offset.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw 2d, you must add 0.5px to U and V coordianates when texturing. This will give you exact pixel/texel precision. Otherwise you will lose 0.5 pixels every time and texture will look blurry.